# Calendar.MONTH calculating different values

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to set a Calendar object's month to a different Month. But I am getting different output when I use two different methods.Current month is June i.e Calendar.MONTH=5

```
Calendar previousCal = Calendar.getInstance();
previousCal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.MONTH-1);
int calMonth = previousCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
System.out.println("CAL month=:"+calMonth);
**Output Value printed = 1**

Calendar newpreviousCal = Calendar.getInstance();
int newPrevMonth = newpreviousCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
newPrevMonth = newPrevMonth -1;
previousCal.set(Calendar.MONTH,newPrevMonth);
int newcalMonth = previousCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
System.out.println("CAL month Nw=:"+newcalMonth);
**Output Value printed = 4**
```

Comment: what do you want to do with "previousCal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.MONTH-1);"?

Comment: I need a day in previous month, so deducting 1 from Current Month and then manipulating the calendar. 2nd output is what I want. Just wondering why first one is not working

Comment: Calendar.MONTH-1 is not the way to retrieve last month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
previousCal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.MONTH-1);
```

Sets the month of the given calendar to `1`, because `Calendar.MONTH` is a constant (`2`) and you're subtracting `1` from it.

If your goal was to subtract one from the calendar's month field, you need both `get` and `set`:

```
previousCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, previousCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
```

...or of course, use [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-):

```
previousCal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```